# mochiron or mochirong

Tags: pronunciation

I've heard it a few times that some Japanese speakers seem to pronounce もちろん as "mochirong", i.e., with more nasal voice than "mochiron".

Is this true, or just my aging ears are fooling me?

Comment: Japanese usually don't differentiate the two sound.

Comment: mochirong sounds more natural.

Answer (score 3):

Your ears aren't fooling you, but it's not 'mochirong' (with a velar sound as in the English sing). When ん comes on the end of a phrase, it can either be pronounced as nasalization and elongation of the previous vowel, or as a uvular nasal (pronounced in the back of the throat).

You use an alveolar nasal before た、な、ざ(but not さ) column kana. Take care that when it comes before a ざ column kana, the z is pronounced dz (which is also used when it comes at the beginning of a word).

You use a bilabial nasal before ぱ、ば、ま column kana (but not は).

You use a velar nasal before か column kana. Notably, が column kana are sometimes pronounced as a velar nasal, and in that case you get a geminated velar nasal.

You nasalize the previous vowel before anything else, including another vowel.

On the end of a phrase, you can have the nasalization, or a uvular nasal.